# Find the default table name after rename

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, m

I have a file in PowerBI that contains some tables all linked to SQL SERVER. My problem is this:

To make user use easier I renamed the tables to a friendlier name, but now I need to know the actual name of the table in the database and I can not find this data.

Where can I find this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go your query editor and open the Advanced Editor for a query that links to the server.

In the first few lines of the M code, you should be able to see exactly how it's connecting and what the SQL table name is. It might look something like this:

```
let
    Source = Sql.Databases("servername"),
    DatabaseName = Source{[Name="DatabaseName"]}[Data],
    TableName = DatabaseName{[Schema="dbo",Item="TableName"]}[Data],
<...>
```